# HTMLElement.prototype.remove

Tags: javascript

Где найти информацию по этому методу? В MDN среди методов HTMLElement, Element, Node такого не нашел. Однако в 58 хроме он присутствует как нативный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно интересует это? Там же есть более полная версия на английском.
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove